# Pulling Wordpress Categories Dynamically

Tags: php, wordpress

I hope someone will be able to help me. I already know how to pull the most recent post in wordpress using this code:

```
<?php query_posts('posts_per_page=1'); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?> 
<h4><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

This works fine, but I want to extend this functionality.  I want to be able to pull posts based on a specific category. For example, the site I'm working on has a page called "Social Media" with information on the topic.  It also has a blog category of the same name. I want to know how I can pull the posts from the Social Media section of the blog to the informational Social Media page (and so on - we will have about 10 more categories which will also need their related posts).

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`wp_list_categories` can help you in this regard. Code will be similar to the following one:

```
<ul>
    <?php wp_list_categories('orderby=books&include=2'); ?>
</ul>
```

Detail can be found here. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_categories

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with code like this:

```
<?php $social_media_id = get_category( 'social-media', ARRAY_A ); ?>
<?php $social_media = query_posts( 'posts_per_page=1,category=' . $social_media_id['cat_ID'] ); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?> 
<h4><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

For the `get_category` part, you could substitute the hard-coded `social-media` with the `$pagename` (if it's the same as the category's name).